intel gpu tools wont work
everytime I try to install intel gpu tools using: sudo apt install intel-gpu-tools then running sudo intel_gpu_top, I get this error:
Failed to initialize PMU! (Permission denied)
I am running this under root in a Proxmox Ubuntu lxc version 22.04
zero idea why it says permission denied...
[update] followed this tutorial to no avail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZDr5h52OOE
link to screenshot of lxc console: https://imgur.com/a/GzrBJav
